# Where is the "Compare" option in Excel (to compare two files)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the current version of Word (heck, I can't even find where the version is any more), In the Review area is a Compare option I use to create a redline from two clean files (where one file is the original and one file has edits).

Where is this option in Excel?

Or what local PC app can do this?

Comment: Excel doesn't have such functionality. You can't just expect any Word functionality to be in Excel. It's a different product.

Comment: @teylyn Thanks! I don't "just expect" anything. I have a need, which I am sure many many others have, and am looking for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the thread "[spreadsheet compare](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/577627/spreadsheet-compare.html)", Spreadsheet Compare is only available with **Office Professional Plus 2013**, **Office Professional Plus 2016**, **Office Professional Plus 2019**, or **Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise**.

To open it, you could search it via Windows search box.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I can add the "Compare and Merge" option to a new tab, but it is disabled.... which I assume means I do not have the right version of Office. (Seems I have Office Home and Business 2019)

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica Sorry, I was confused at first time. The Compare and Merge Workbooks is apply for shared workbooks to merge changes from multiple users．

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I need.... problem is I don't seem to have it (and the upgrade path from my Office to that Office is.... not clear). Total hassle.